# Is the copy-list-initialization for class object a user-defined conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Data{
   Data(int){
   }
}
int main(){
  Data d = {0};  //#1
}
```

As the above code show,Does the #1 invocation contain a user-defined conversion?In my understanding about the standard ,I think it does not
For copy-list-initialization rules [[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.6)

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed

[[over.match.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list)

> If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list

The standard only said the best match constructor is used to initialize the object which is initialized by using the element of `initializer list`,it is different with copy-initialization(the copy-initialization say that "**user-defined** conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type",explicit define the copy-initialization need a user-defined conversion)
So `Data d = {0}; => Data d(0);` there's no user-defined conversion other than standard conversions?Is my understanding right?
However another terms [[class.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv#1)

> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause [conv]), for initialization, and for explicit type conversions

the above term means if the initialized destination type  is class type and need to use constructors or conversion functions,then the conversions are "user-defined conversions"
I'm confused by these terms,what actually the `Data d = {0};` is a user-defined conversion or not?

Comment: Your example is exactly the one given in the standard (third one)... There is no need for any conversion here. So, what ?

Comment: what's the third one ,could you pass the example here or a more detail answers

Comment: The one in [dcl.init.list]...

Comment: yes,i see ,however the example does not clear explain whether the initialization is a conversion...and  in the short,Is my understand right   about  that the copy-list-initialization for the case I refered  has no  user-defined conversion ?

Comment: Then you would have mean in `Data d = 0;` not in `Data d = { 0 };`. Right?

Comment: no,only for Data d = {0}; case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208580/discussion-between-jack-x-and-jean-baptiste-yunes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions.

User-defined conversion is first a type conversion. In the initialization `Data d = {0};`, there is even no type conversion, thus no user-defined conversion.

Comment: change the context,such as `void func(Data);` for `func({0})` It is a conceptly user-defined conversion  for overload resolution,right?

Comment: @jackX Conceptual conversions are different from actual conversions and are only used for the purpose of overload resolution. I assume you are talking about actual conversions.

Comment: yes,I know,for the actual conversion `Data d = { 0 };` there's  no conversion except standard conversion ,and for the overload resolution such as `func({0})`,it is conceptly user-defined conversion ,My quesion in the comment is for the another quesion you haven't answered me,thanks

Comment: @jackX But there is no overload resolution requiring a conversion from `0` to `Data`, so it makes no sense to ask whether it contains such conceptual user-defined conversions.

Comment: exactly,the quesion in the comment about  overload resolution is for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406254/whats-the-rank-of-implicitly-conversion-for-copy-list-initialization/60406525?noredirect=1#comment106871347_60406525

Comment: @jackX I have said it in that answer: "All the three conversions `{0} -> A`, `{0} -> const B&`, `{0} -> B&&` are user-defined conversions. "

Comment: Since there are all in overload resolution, speciafilly,for `{0}->A` it's the conceptly user-defined conversion ,Is my understanding right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208685/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-jack-x).